# Full screen nav jumps due to lack of scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a full screen overlay nav, which when triggered hides the overflow on the `html` element. This is to stop the page behind the nav being scrolled when the nav is open.

Stripped down SCSS (when nav is active) looks like this:

```css
    html.nav-is-active {
      overflow: hidden
    }
    
    nav.active {
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 1600000;
    }
```

My problem is when the nav is open the scrollbar disappears causing the page to jump - this is especially disorientating as there is a close button on the nav overlay which is supposed to line up with a menu button on the site.

My question is how can I best solve this? I can remove the `overflow:hidden` from the `html` element to preserve the scrollbar, but that then means the site can be scrolled unintentionally when the nav is open.

Any help appreciated

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This is really hacky, but it should do what you want...

```
html {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow-y: scroll; // causes an empty scrollbar
  height: auto; //set height = content so body can't overflow
}
```

You can make your scrollbar visible the same way in the overlay.

OR If you can figure out the width of the scrollbar (typically 15px on Mac and *I think* similar in Win 10) you can subtract from the overlay size or add padding. This is slightly better than setting the overlay to `overflow-y: scroll` since it won't cause scrolling INSIDE the overlay on small screens.

```
nav.active {
  width: calc(100vw - 15px); // could be done with javascript
}
```

Comment: Just `html.nav-is-active {position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll;}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to block scroll without `overflow: hidden;` is `position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll;` so simply change this:

```
html.nav-is-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

with this:

```
html.nav-is-active {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

You'll se an empty scroll bar, but the page will not "jump" anymore.